# Query string to add product and apply promo code: M2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, discount, coupon

I currently have set up a query string that automatically adds a set amount of products to the users cart when they click a specific button. I already have everything set with with the FormKey() and this is working as expected.

**Working**

```
domain.com/checkout/cart/add/product/13/qty/6/
```

I can also in an entirely different URL apply a specific promo code to the shopping cart

**Working**

```
domain.com/checkout/cart/couponPost/coupon_code/PROMOCODE/
```

However, I am unable to do both at the same time. I would like to build one URL that adds specific products to the users cart and then applies the promotional code. I would expect this URL to work....

**Does not work**

```
domain.com/checkout/cart/add/product/13/qty/6/couponPost/coupon_code/PROMOCODE/
```

But it does not. Is there any way to accomplish what I am looking for?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone who might come across this later, my free and open source discount code url module might help in this situation: https://github.com/crankycyclops/DiscountCodeUrl